# Importing IReact type definition

Tags: typescript, konvajs, react-konva, konva, konvajs-reactjs

I have a variable that holds a **Group Reference** and when I call **getClientRect()** it returns the "IReact" type.

Since IReact is not in the default types index should I import the type from the internal types file or is there a better approach?

Simplified code reference:

```
import { IRect } from './../../../node_modules/konva/types/types';

const groupRef: React.RefObject<Konva.Group> = React.createRef();
const groupAttrsAux: IRect | undefined = groupRef.current?.getClientRect(null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never import from `node_modules`. Shouldn't this work?

`import { IRect } from "konva/types/types";`

Comment: Yes it does, thanks for the warning. Is this the best way to solve this situation then? Simply import IRect directly?

Comment: Yes, it's exported in the package for you to import. Of course, you could fully re-define the type yourself, or use `ReturnType` on `typeof getClientRect`, but that would be ugly and unnecessary.